# Add a geom layer for a single panel in a faceted plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Taking a cue from the following link [Aligning two plots with ggplot2](http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=tips:graphics-ggplot2:aligntwoplots), I was able to plot 2 "y" variables faceted against a common x axis. What I want to do now is to be able to add a geom_point layer to only one of the facets. This layer uses a different dataset(d3) with a same structure as d1. When I add the layer it gets used on both facets. Is it possible to layer the points only the upper facet.

```
library(ggplot2)

x <- seq(1992, 2002, by = 2)
d1 <- data.frame(x = x, y = rnorm(length(x)))
xy <- expand.grid(x = x, y = x)
d2 <- data.frame(x = xy$x, y = xy$y, z = jitter(xy$x + xy$y))
d3 <- data.frame(x = x, y = 3+rnorm(length(x)))

d1$panel <- "a"
d2$panel <- "b"
d1$z <- d1$x

d <- rbind(d1, d2)

p <- ggplot(data = d, mapping = aes(x = x, y = y))
p <- p + facet_grid(panel ~ ., scale = "free")
p <- p + layer(data = d1,  geom = c( "line"), stat = "identity")
###*p <- p + layer(data = d3,  geom = c( "point"))* - This is the layer I intend to add only to the top panel

p <- p + layer(data = d2,  geom = "line", stat = "identity")
p
```

Comment: +1, well phrased question with a reproducible example

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just add the `panel` column to `d3` with the panel you want to add the point set to. In your case:

```
d3$panel = "a"

p <- ggplot(data = d, mapping = aes(x = x, y = y))
p <- p + facet_grid(panel ~ ., scale = "free")
p <- p + layer(data = d1,  geom = c( "line"), stat = "identity")
p <- p + layer(data = d3,  geom = c( "point"))
p <- p + layer(data = d2,  geom = "line", stat = "identity")
p
```

which yields the correct output:

[image]

If the column mentioned in the call to `facet_grid` is not present, ggplot2 assumes it needs to be printed on all facets. When you specify `panel`, ggplot2 will take it into account.

Comment: +1 Thanks, Paul. That was easy ! In a related question, like in lattice is there a way to get the index of the panel number to be able to customize individual panels (similar to panel.subscripts() from lattice).

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean. I suggest you create a new question where you provide more detail, and some example code.

Comment: ggplot2 has no panel number as it would be against its philosophy; instead, you refer to a given panel by its corresponding facetting variable(s).