# ggplot2 geom_rect not scale appropriately under facet_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, facet-wrap

The question is: `geom_rect` prevents the **scaling** of `facet_grid` using ggplot2.

I am wondering whether it is caused by conflict in two data frames, but don't know how to solve this issue. Hope you can help me.

A sample code is follows:

```
library(ggplot2)
data_1 <- data.frame(x = c(seq(from = 1, to = 10, by = 1),
                           seq(from = 21, to = 50, by = 1)),
                     y = rnorm(40, mean = 3, sd = 1),
                     z = c(rep("A", 10), rep("B", 30)))

shade <- 
  data.frame(xmin = c(2, 6, 39),
             xmax = c(3, 8, 43),
             ymin = - Inf,
             ymax = Inf)
```

If not using `geom_rect`, I can scale with `facet_grid` appropriately like this:

```
ggplot(data = data_1, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "blue") +
  facet_grid(.~z, space = "free_x", scales = "free_x")
```

the result is like this:

[image]

But if I draw some `geom_rect`, then the scale previously shown disappeared, with code and graph like this:

```
ggplot(data = data_1, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "blue") +
  geom_rect(data = shade, inherit.aes = FALSE,
            mapping = aes(xmin = xmin, 
                          xmax = xmax, 
                          ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax),
            fill = 'red', alpha = 0.2) +
  facet_grid(.~z, space = "free_x", scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

How to **keep** the previous **scaling on x** while drawing these `geom_rect`?

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add the geoms after facetting (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10673877) or draw two separate plots and piece them together with 'patchwork' package (https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork).

Comment: In this situation, the sequence doesn't matter. I don't know how to use "patchwork".

Comment: It really is easy. Just follow the vignettes on the github repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The x-axis range changes because data in the `geom_rect` layer extends beyond that of the original plot. The scale is doing exactly what it's expected to do.

If you want different rectangles to show up for each facet, it would be cleaner to include the facet variable in `shade`, & keep only the rows with `xmin` / `xmax` *within* the range of each facet. For example:

```
library(dplyr)
shade2 <- shade %>%
  # add facet-specific x-axis range information from data_1
  tidyr::crossing(data_1 %>% group_by(z) %>%
                    summarise(x1 = min(x),
                              x2 = max(x)) %>%
                    ungroup) %>%

  # filter for rects within each facet's x-axis range
  group_by(z) %>%
  filter(xmin >= x1 & xmax <= x2) %>%
  ungroup()

> shade2
# A tibble: 3 x 7
   xmin  xmax  ymin  ymax z        x1    x2
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
1     2     3  -Inf   Inf A         1    10
2     6     8  -Inf   Inf A         1    10
3    39    43  -Inf   Inf B        21    50
```

Plot:

```
ggplot(data = data_1, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_col(fill = "blue") + # geom_col is equivalent to geom_bar(stat = "identity")
  geom_rect(data = shade2, inherit.aes = FALSE,
            mapping = aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, 
                          ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax),
            fill = 'red', alpha = 0.2) +
  facet_grid(.~z, space = "free_x", scales = "free_x")
```

[image: result]